# Extract random values from list that fulfil criteria? Python

Tags: python, random

Is it possible to use the random module to extract strings from a list, but only if the string has a length greater than x?

For example:

```
list_of_strings = ['Hello', 'Hello1' 'Hello2']
```

If you set `x = 5` and call `random.choice()` the code would be 'choosing' between only `list_of_strings[1]` and `list_of_strings[2]`.

I realise you could make a second list which contains only values of `len > x` but i would like to know if it is possible without this step.

Comment: IOW, it's possible using a loop, but probably better to just use comprehension.

Comment: not so sure but comprehensions are also creating another list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
random.choice([s for s in list_of_strings if len(s) > x])
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
while True:
    choice = random.choice(list_of_strings)
    if len(choice) > x:
        return choice
```

You should check first if there are strings in the list that are longer than x, otherwise that code will never end.

Another possible solution is to use reservoir sampling, it has the additional benefit of having a bounded running time.

Comment: *"I realise you could make a second list which contains only values of len > x but i would like to know if it is possible without this step."*

Comment: It will also be slow if there are not many elements that satisfy the condition. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that doesn't create an additional list:

```
from itertools import islice
from random import randrange

def choose_if(f, s):
  return next(islice(filter(f, s), randrange(sum(map(f, s))), None))

choose_if(lambda x: len(x) > 5, list_of_strings)
```

Turns out it is almost two times slower than Christian's solution. That's because it iterates over `s` twice, applying `f` to every element. It is expensive enough to outweigh the gain from not creating a second list.

Francisco's solution, on the other hand, can be 10 to 100 times faster than that, because it applies `f` only as many times as it failed to pick a suitable element. Here's a complete version of that function:

```
from random import choice

def choose_if(f, s):
  if any(filter(f, s)):
    while True:
      x = choice(s)
      if f(x): return x
```

Bear in mind it starts to get worse when few (less than 1%) elements satisfy the condition. When only 1 element in 5000 was good, it was 5 times slower than using a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
random.choice([i for i in list_of_strings if len(i) > x])
```

Comment: *"I realise you could make a second list which contains only values of len > x but i would like to know if it is possible without this step."*